# Connecting to ArcSDE with ArcSDE Geoserver extension?

Tags: geoserver, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a server running Geoserver 2.8 with the ArcSDE extension installed. I have added a new "ArcSDE ESRI(tm) ArcSDE 9.2+ vector data store" with credentials from our DBA.

When I try to add a layer I only see a tiny subset of the layers that should be there. Talking with the DBA it appears the majority of the layers are prefixed with "SDE_" and it is these layers that are not showing up.

We are not connecting with the SYSTEM, DBA or SDE users. I know the layers are prefixed with "SDE_" because when talking to the database guy here he said "We just name them like that so we know they're spatially enabled rather than just tabular when looking through the schema listing"

Does anybody know why these layers are not able to be loaded by the extension? Is there a way of making the extension load them?

- Database: Oracle Standard Edition One
- Version: 11.2.0.2
- ArcSDE Version: 10.0
- ArcGIS Geodatabase Version: 10.0 for Oracle11g Build 2004
- SDE Client library: jpe_sdk.jar & jsde_sdk.jar (Created-By: 1.4.2_12 (Sun Microsystems Inc.), Specification-Version: 9.3)
- JDBC Driver version: ojdbc6.jar (Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.4.0, Repository-Id: JAVAVM_11.2.0.4.0_LINUX.X64_RELEASE)
- Apache Tomcat version: 7.0.65

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this question without more information about the data in the database.  Please **edit** the question to include the database, the database version, the ArcGIS geodatabase version, and the ArcSDE client library version.  It is a violation of best security practices to connect as a highly privileged user (not SYSTEM, not DBA, not SDE, not even as the table owner).  How do you know the layers are prefixed with "SDE_"? (This would also be a violation of best practice.)  Are they *layers* or *tables*?

Comment: We are not connecting with the SYSTEM, DBA or SDE users. I know the layers are prefixed with "SDE_" because when talking to the database guy here he said "We just name them like that so we know they're spatially enabled rather than just tabular when looking through the schema listing"

Comment: I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] that all users of this site are expected to, in order to become familiar with its procedures.

Comment: @PolyGeo Correct, but the Tour is the same as the one on the other 11 stackexchange sites I am a member of :-)

Comment: Compare them to see that like many other sites our community has customized its [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

We have almost exactly this same problem, same versions of everything except our SDE has been upgraded using the scripts from ArcGIS Pro 1.1, and I have tried using, alternately, the .jar file jpe_sdk.jar from 10.1 as well as 10.2.2, which is called jpe_10.2_sdk.jar.  I can't seem to find that file in the 10.3.1 ArcGIS Server install, which indicates to me that things are changing internally.

We have users SDE_ADMIN (data owner), SDE_WEB (read-only), SDE_USER1 (editor), etc., and nothing is showing up at all to viewer, editor, or creator role users.  If I deliberately type an incorrect username or password it does not connect.  Otherwise I can create a store and connect, but not see anything, and SDE_ADMIN owns almost all the tables.  Even tested it as the SDE schema owner, still no luck.

In the past with an older version of SDE, I think 9.2 on Oracle 9i, and a somewhat older install of GeoServer, I was able to connect and see the layers.  I think there is an internal schema difference in later SDE's (possibly since they moved to using ST_GEOMETRY instead of their old kind?) that the GeoServer extension can no longer understand.